# Как правильно вывести число Y?

Tags: c++, математика

Дано двузначное целое число .
Все цифры должны быть не равны нулю.
Определить четырехзначное число  :

- первая цифра  равна остатку от деления на 10 произведения всех цифр
  числа ;
- вторая цифра равна остатку от деления второй цифры числа  на первую
  цифру числа ;
- третья цифра  равна остатку от деления суммы всех цифр числа  на
  вторую цифру числа .
- четвертая цифра  равна остатку от деления первой цифры числа  на
  вторую цифру числа ;
  Должно быть выведено именно число , (оно может иметь меньше разрядов,
  если первые цифры получатся равными нулю), а не выведены на экран последовательно
  четыре цифры.
  Вот мой код:

```
//Вывести число Y
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int x;
    cout << "Введите двузначное число: ";
    cin >> x;
    int d[4];
    for (int i = 0; x; x % 10 *d[0]*d[1]*d[2]*d[3] )
        d[i++] = d[2] % d[1];
    for (int i1 = 0; x; x % 10 * x)
    d[i1++] = d[3] % d[2];
    for (int i2 = 0; x; x % 10 * x)
    d[i2++] = d[1] % d[2];
    x = d[3]+d[2] * 100 + d[1] * 10 + d[0];
    cout << x;
}
```

Думаю здесь можно обойтись без цикла for и избавиться от массива. Но я плохо представляю как произвести рефакторинг кода. Можете подсказать как правильно реализовать условие задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да чтож это такое... :)

```
int x2 = x%10;
int x1 = x/10;

int y3 = (x1*x2)%10;
int y2 = x2%x1;
int y1 = (x1+x2)%x2;
int y0 = x1%x2;

int y = y3*1000+y2*100+y1*10+y0;
```

Какие того же типа задания будут дальше?

Comment: X-то двузначное)

Comment: @vp_arth  Квиты. Да, не заметил...

Comment: Эх,сложное заданьице,вот при этой компиляции выводит то же самое число которое и вводишь.@Mikhailo

Comment: А вы случайно не x выводите? `cout << x;`? Считаете y, а выводите x? Ой, какая прелесть! :)

Comment: Надо бы перечитать код и разобраться в нём:)А то и вправду выходит какая-то несуразица...

Answer (score 0):

```
// X=xw
// Y=yzta

x = X / 10
w = X % 10

y = (x * w) % 10
z = w % y
t = (x + w) % w
a = x % w

Y = ((y * 10 + z) * 10 + t) * 10 + a
```

Comment: Ааа!!! Не компилируется! )))

Comment: Беда) Точку с запятой где-нибудь забыл)

Comment: Хм,у меня не выводится четырёхзначное число которое по условию должно вывестись.Например,  = 35, тогда  = 5233.Выводится однозначное @vp_arth

Comment: очевидно, что выводите x, который у меня - первая цифра числа X